# Cannot change raw resource after some time with Runnable and Handler

Tags: android, android-studio, runnable, android-handler

I am developing android app for kids to learn alphabates and for that I want to change appropriate image resource and raw file after one raw ends. I have created Arrays of Image and raw resources from that I am getting id's but the problem is nothing is updated.
here is how I am doing this

```
public class Alpha_Loop extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView abc,img1;
int i = 0;
int ab;
int playsound;
Runnable Rn;
int s = 0;
long updatetime;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
Handler handler;
//Array of Image1
final int[] ImageArray = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e,
        R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h, R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j, R.drawable.k,
        R.drawable.l, R.drawable.m, R.drawable.n, R.drawable.o, R.drawable.p, R.drawable.q,
        R.drawable.r, R.drawable.s, R.drawable.t, R.drawable.u, R.drawable.v, R.drawable.w,
        R.drawable.x, R.drawable.y, R.drawable.z};

//Array of Image1
final int[] img1Array = {R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.ball, R.drawable.cat, R.drawable.dog, R.drawable.egg,
        R.drawable.fish, R.drawable.goat, R.drawable.hat, R.drawable.insect, R.drawable.jar,
        R.drawable.king, R.drawable.leaf, R.drawable.monkey, R.drawable.nose, R.drawable.ocean,
        R.drawable.parrot, R.drawable.queen, R.drawable.rat, R.drawable.sun, R.drawable.tap,
        R.drawable.umbrella, R.drawable.violin, R.drawable.well, R.drawable.box, R.drawable.yatch,
        R.drawable.zebra};
//Array of wav files
final int[] Soundid = {R.raw.a, R.raw.a, R.raw.b, R.raw.c, R.raw.d, R.raw.e,
        R.raw.f, R.raw.g, R.raw.h, R.raw.i, R.raw.j, R.raw.k,
        R.raw.l, R.raw.m, R.raw.n, R.raw.o, R.raw.p, R.raw.q,
        R.raw.r, R.raw.s, R.raw.t, R.raw.u, R.raw.v, R.raw.w,
        R.raw.x, R.raw.y, R.raw.z};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alpha__loop);
    abc = findViewById(R.id.abc);
    img1 = findViewById(R.id.img1);
    aa();

}
public void aa(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Rn = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            abc.setImageResource(ImageArray[ab]);
            ab++;
            if (i == ImageArray.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            img1.setImageResource(img1Array[i]);
            i++;
            if (i == img1Array.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            playsound = Soundid[s];
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Alpha_Loop.this, Soundid[s]);
            s++;
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
            updatetime =  mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            if (s >= Soundid.length) {
                s = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(Rn, updatetime);

}

}
```

I am totally noob and code seems to be ok for me, I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you et any error somewhere?

Comment: No error apear just one raw is playing

Comment: A `Runnable` does not automatically repeat itself. You're only posting it once – `handler.postDelayed(Rn, updatetime);` – and after it finishes that run, it's done. I would also point out that it looks like you've mixed up some of the array index variables; particularly, `ab` and `i`. You should really use meaningful variable names, so it's less likely for that to happen.